# php string convert to html

Tags: php, character

I have a string `&lt;div id="myid"&gt;`...`&lt;/div&gt;`

How would I change this into 
`<div id="myid">`...`</div>`

I have tried a few things but no luck any help?

**Update**

```
function get_page(){
  $file = 'file.php';
  $str = file_get_contents($file);
  $str = html_entity_decode($str);
  return $str;
}
$output = get_page();
echo $output;//don't work
```

**FIX**

```
function get_page(){
      $file = 'file.php';
      $str = file_get_contents($file);
      return $str;
    }
    $output = get_page();
    echo html_entity_decode($output);//works
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The function for that is [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode).

Note that for the function to decode quotes, you need to specify the `$quote_style` parameter.

Comment: @Val what result do you get? What code do you use? You are using it like this: `$string = htmlspecialchars_decode($string);`, right?

Comment: yes , and `$str =   htmlspecialchars_decode($str,ENT_NOQUOTES);` still doesn't work. I save it into a file using `fwrite`, wen i try to output it to html it comes up as plain text not html element, if that helps

Comment: @Val your problem is most likely elsewhere. Try a `echo $str;` to see the output

Comment: hmm Your right... watch my update and try and help me where im going wrong.

Comment: the problem is there on the `return $str`

Comment: @Val what is the problem? What do you mean by "works" and "doesn't work"?

Comment: when i use the echo on the function it prints out the div properly and the image inside it. doesn't work means when i use return it just shows `<div>...</div>` on the browser.

Comment: @Val please show the actual code you are using. Also if you just output the page, it might get displayed as `text/plain` instead of `text/html`

Comment: using an mvc so it would be quite difficult to show the whole code

Comment: @Val well, the code you are showing doesn't make much sense. For starters, it doesn't contain a `htmlspecialchars_decode()` call. Also its not clear what the problem really is. Where do you get the wrong entities?

Comment: if it made sense i wouldn't be here :) lol Like I said on my `view` page I have `<?php echo $output; ?>` then  `get_file()` is used on my controller. which it literally has that many lines...`file.php` has normal html inside.when i use the `echo $str; ` inside that `get_file` i can see an image which is on the `file.php` when i use `return $str; ` i get `<div><img ... /> </div>`

Comment: @Val and if you look into the source code, you see `&gt` etc.?

Comment: yes, I should mention i have `<body><div id="header">blabla</div><div>&lt;div id="myid"&gt;...&lt;/div&gt;</div></body>` thats source code and on browser i see `blabla <div id="myid">....</div>`

Comment: @Val you must have a function call or filter somewhere that does a `htmlspecialchars()` on the content. I have no other explanation

Comment: Look at my updated answer and the fix I found for it ... Any ideas what the hell was that about?

Comment: @Val then your source file must contain the `&gt; &lt;`s?

Comment: @Pekka I found a fix ... it looks like when i used the `html_entity_decode` outside the `get_page` function it works, using it inside the function it does not work

Comment: @Pekka also the source using `fix` option (on updated answer) looks nice and I can see the picture.

Answer (score 2):

`html_entity_decode` is what you need: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$from = array('&lt;', '&gt;');
$to = array('<', '>');
$string = str_replace($from, $to, $string);
```

Comment: I could be here a year trying to figure out all the individual characters and secondly that could slow the page down,

Answer (score 1):

**use this it's better ...**

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";
// Allow <p> and <a>

echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($string)
```